# sympy is unable to solve a set of equation

Tags: python, math, sympy

I have a mode, a maximum and minimum value of X (`Xmin` and `Xmax`), and a percentage confidence (`percentage`).

I want to use the following functions in order to find the `μ` and `σ` of a theoretical log normal distribution:

The cumulative distribution function:

[image: CDF]

and the mode

[image: mode]

I decided to solve it as a set of equation. in the example I use arbitrary values of `mode`, `percentage`, `Xmin` and `Xmax`

```
from sympy import *

def CalcScaleParamSET (mode, percentage, Xmin, Xmax):

    s = Symbol('s', Real=True)
    mu = Symbol('mu', Real =True)

    eqn1 = (1/2+1/2*erf((log(Xmax)-mu)/sqrt(2)*s)-1/2-1/2*erf((log(Xmin)-mu)/sqrt(2)*s)) -percentage
    eqn2 = (exp(mu-s**2)) - mode

    eqns = [eqn1, eqn2]

    ans = linsolve(eqns, s, mu)

    print(ans)

CalcScaleParamSET(2, 0.95, 1, 4)
```

This returns an `EmptySet()` meaning that sympy cannot find a solution to the equation. I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong, is it a mathematics problem or a code issue? I wrote a matlab script to perform the same task and it was able to come up with a single numerical value of `μ` and `σ`.

Comment: linsolve solves linear equations.

Comment: I thought my equations were linear?

Comment: I think linear only works for `a*x + b*y - c` type of equations.

Comment: I see mu and s inside of exp and erf functions. So very nonlinear.

Comment: `solve` would be a better fit here, but it seems it cannot find a symbolic solution. `solve` only finds symbolic solutions, so if you want a numeric solution you should use a numeric solver such as `sympy.nsolve`.